# Gatsby js loading indicator documentation

Tags: gatsby

I can't find any documentation on loading indicator customisation.
There is a default loading indicator that is displayed if the page is not loaded in 1 second after the user request. Is there a way to customise it or disable it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only shown during `gatsby develop` and can be customized, see the "Loading indicator" section of https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/27620.

e.g. access `http://localhost:8000/___loading-indicator/disable` during `gatsby develop`.